# In C#, does copying a member variable to a local stack variable improve performance?

Tags: c#, performance

I quite often write code that copies member variables to a local stack variable in the belief that it will improve performance by removing the pointer dereference that has to take place whenever accessing member variables.

Is this valid?

For example

```
public class Manager {
    private readonly Constraint[] mConstraints;

    public void DoSomethingPossiblyFaster() 
    {
        var constraints = mConstraints;
        for (var i = 0; i < constraints.Length; i++) 
        {
            var constraint = constraints[i];
            // Do something with it
        }
    }

    public void DoSomethingPossiblySlower() 
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < mConstraints.Length; i++) 
        {
            var constraint = mConstraints[i];
            // Do something with it
        }
    }

}
```

My thinking is that DoSomethingPossiblyFaster is actually faster than DoSomethingPossiblySlower.

I know this is pretty much a micro optimisation, but it would be useful to have a definitive answer.

**Edit**
Just to add a little bit of background around this. Our application has to process a lot of data coming from telecom networks, and this method is likely to be called about 1 billion times a day for some of our servers. My view is that every little helps, and sometimes all I am trying to do is give the compiler a few hints.

Comment: have you profiled it?

Comment: Maybe the time that you earn by doing this is "lost" because of the time that it requires to copy the pointer to another memory location (we are talking about micro optimization so I think they are reasonable things to think about).

Comment: Agreed, if anything you're just adding one more reference to be maintained.

Comment: @mike, even if he had profiled it, an explanation as to why would still be a useful artifact.

Comment: @Rodrick Chapman, if he had profiled it, that information would have been useful to include in the OP.  And since he asked "does" instead of "why does", we can only assume he hasn't profiled it yet.  In the general scheme of things, he will probably get more out of Mikeb's one-liner than any answer posted.  Teach a man to fish and all that...

Comment: I'm not really interested in profiling this. I'm trying to understand whether or not this micro optimisation _should_ work. I actually think Jon's answer is the correct one - what is more readable. And I agree that the micro optimisation one is not more readable.

Comment: That's not a micro-optimization; that's a nano-optimization. You almost certainly have problems that are *thousands* or *millions* of times larger than this one. You have a yard full of blackberry brambles and you're trying to improve the appearance of the lawn by adjusting individual blades of grass with tweezers. Spend your time clearing out the brambles instead.

Comment: "getting a haircut to lose weight" Wish I could the original of that remark.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**If** the compiler/JIT isn't already doing this or a similar optimization for you (this is a big if), then `DoSomethingPossiblyFaster` should be faster than `DoSomethingPossiblySlower`.  The best way to explain why is to look at a rough translation of the C# code to straight C.

When a non-static member function is called, a hidden pointer to `this` is passed into the function.  You'd have roughly the following, ignoring virtual function dispatch since it's irrelevant to the question (or equivalently making `Manager` sealed for simplicity):

```
struct Manager {
    Constraint* mConstraints;
    int mLength;
}

void DoSomethingPossiblyFaster(Manager* this) {
    Constraint* constraints = this->mConstraints;
    int length = this->mLength;


    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
    {
        Constraint constraint = constraints[i];
        // Do something with it
    }
 }

void DoSomethingPossiblySlower() 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < this->mLength; i++) 
    {
        Constraint constraint = (this->mConstraints)[i];
        // Do something with it
    }
}
```

The difference is that in `DoSomethingPossiblyFaster`, `mConstraints` lives on the stack and access only requires one layer of pointer indirection, since it's at a fixed offset from the stack pointer.  In `DoSomethingPossiblySlower`, if the compiler misses the optimization opportunity, there's an extra pointer indirection.  The compiler has to read a fixed offset from the stack pointer to access `this` and then read a fixed offset from `this` to get `mConstraints`.

There are two possible optimizations that could negate this hit:

1. The compiler could do exactly what you did manually and cache `mConstraints` on the stack.
2. The compiler could store `this` in a register so that it doesn't need to fetch it from the stack on every loop iteration before dereferencing it.  This means that fetching `mConstraints` from `this` or from the stack is basically the same operation:  A single dereference of a fixed offset from a pointer that's already in a register.

Comment: Now that's more like the answer I was expecting. Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

Which is more *readable*? That should usually be your primary motivating factor. Do you even need to use a `for` loop instead of `foreach`?

As `mConstraints` is `readonly` I'd *potentially* expect the JIT compiler to do this for you - but really, what are you doing in the loop? The chances of this being significant are pretty small. I'd almost *always* pick the second approach simply for readability - and I'd prefer `foreach` where possible. Whether the JIT compiler optimizes this case will very much depend on the JIT itself - which may vary between versions, architectures, and even how large the method is or other factors. There can *be* no "definitive" answer here, as it's always possible that an alternative JIT will optimize differently.

If you think you're in a corner case where this really *matters*, you should benchmark it - thoroughly, with as realistic data as possible. *Only then* should you change your code away from the most readable form. If you're "quite often" writing code like this, it seems unlikely that you're doing yourself any favours.

Even if the readability difference is relatively small, I'd say it's still present and significant - whereas I'd certainly *expect* the performance difference to be negligible.

Comment: +1 and even if you are the only person coding on this stuff, come back to it in a months time after having been away from it and try to understand the stuff again lol bet you can't, just like not being able to read your own handwriting.

Comment: -1.  This is a cop-out answer.  Wanting to know whether x should be faster than y is a legitimate question.  Benchmarking can be noisy when the difference is very small.  The OP may have asked this because he/she wanted a better mental model of how computers work under the hood, rather than for direct practical value.

Comment: @dsimcha: The OP asked for a definitive answer, and I've explained why that is infeasible.

Comment: @Jon:  I gave him the closest thing feasible to a definitive answer since, as you say, there isn't a definitive answer.  You gave him a lecture on something tangentially relevant.  It's a matter of compiler optimizations and I explained what would happen assuming an extremely dumb compiler and what compiler optimizations could potentially negate that effect.

Comment: @dsimcha: The trouble is, I feel the question is based on a flawed premise: "it would be useful to have a definitive answer" - my answer is basically saying that no, that's *not* useful (even if it were possible to be definitive) unless you're in a real corner case where it actually makes a difference - in which case it should be *measurable*. I don't think it's *tangentially* relevant - he says this is the kind of code he writes "quite often" and basically I'm saying to stop doing that, and why.

Answer (score 3):

You know the response you will get, right?   "Time it."

There is probably not a definitive answer.   First, the compiler might do the optimization for you.   Second,  even if it doesn't, indirect addressing at the assembly level may not be significantly slower.   Third, it depends on the cost of making the local copy, compared to the number of loop iterations.    Then there are caching effects to consider.

I love to optimize, but this is one place I would definitely say wait until you have a problem, then experiment.    This is a possible optimization that can be added when needed, not one of those optimizations that needs to be planned up front to avoid a massive ripple effect later.

---

Edit:  (towards  a definitive answer)

Compiling both functions in release mode and examining the IL with [IL Dasm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) shows that in both places the "PossiblyFaster" function uses the local variable, it has one less instruction
    `ldloc.0` vs
    `ldarg.0; ldfld      class Constraint[] Manager::mConstraints`

Of course, this is still one level removed from the machine code - you don't know what the JIT compiler will do for you.   But it is likely that "PossiblyFaster" is marginally faster.
However, I still don't recommend adding the extra variable until you are sure this function is the most expensive thing in your system.

Comment: Ak! I've been Skeeted!  Just because he types faster and gives a better answer, I don't know why he gets all the votes ;)

Comment: There should be a tax on SO rep :)

Answer (score 1):

I've profiled this and came up with a bunch of interesting results that are probably only valid for my specific example, but I thought would be worth while noting here.

The fastest is X86 release mode. That runs one iteration of my test in 7.1 seconds, whereas the equivalent X64 code takes 8.6 seconds. This was running 5 iterations, each iteration processing the loop 19.2 million times.

The fastest approach for the loop was:

```
foreach (var constraint in mConstraints)
{
   ... do stuff ...
}
```

The second fastest approach, which massively surprised me was the following

```
for (var i = 0; i < mConstraints.Length; i++)
{
    var constraint = mConstraints[i];
    ... do stuff ...
}
```

I guess this was because mConstraints was stored in a register for the loop.

This slowed down when I removed the readonly option for mConstraints.

So, my summary from this is that being *readable* in this situation does give performance as well.