# In C#, why assign member variables to local variables and then use local variables instead of using member variables directly

Tags: c#, .net, variables, compiler-construction

In C#, why assign member variables to local variables and then use local variables instead of using member variables directly, as shown in the following snippet:

```
internal class LocalVariableTest
{
    private readonly int[] _items = new[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };


    public void ConsoleWriteLine()
    {
        var items = _items;

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }

    public void ConsoleWriteLine2()
    {
        foreach (var item in _items)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

What is the difference between ConsoleWriteLine and ConsoleWriteLine2?

I would like to know if there is any difference between the two methods after compiling. I have seen many places that have this way of writing. Which one has higher performance and where is the knowledge about this, such as Microsoft Learn?

Comment: Is this a real snippet or a made up example? There are reasons to do this sometimes, but *in this case* I found no difference in the resulting assembly code at all

Comment: "_I have seen many places that have this way of writing._" It's not improving readability, it's not ensuring thread-safety (in case the array is manipulated and accessed concurrently), it's not simplifying code. This form of code you posted where the value of a readonly field itself is simply assigned to a local variable like that and nothing else is pretty much pointless...

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace it (ie the idea of copy-to-local in general) should not be dismissed entirely, there are other cases in which it helps. For example [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBDAzgWwB8ABAJgEYBYAKGIGYACMhgYQYG8aHuGAHKAJYA3bBhgNY2ACYQAdgBsAngwGyMAbQC6DbFCjZFAbi48T3ekxQMAsuQAUASg5me3AGbQGd1RhUMAvAwADIZ+ADwM5EEhKgDUsQ4urq66+orqAtqBAsbUrgC+Li4WxFbWpI7OecncIlAM8hBg2PIBOnoGuTXunt5qfoExAgwRUUPxidXdPI3N8hlZKl08hdT5QA===) where the version with copy-to-local has a form of bounds check elimination

Comment: "I have seen many places that have this way of writing." the link [https://github.com/kerryjiang/SuperSocket/blob/master/src/SuperSocket.Channel/PipeChannel.cs](https://github.com/kerryjiang/SuperSocket/blob/master/src/SuperSocket.Channel/PipeChannel.cs). The methods FillPipeAsync, ProcessSends, ReadPipeAsync ...

Comment: @harold, that's interesting. Thanks for sharing! (I guess, although i am just speculating, that might indicate that readonly fields are not really read-only on the IL/CLR level. Hmm, i have to try setting such a readonly field through reflection and see what happens...)

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace indeed readonly fields can be modified via reflection (and other means, unsafe code certainly, and probably via a `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]` trick) (and if it's a field in a struct, [readonly is a lie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6063546/555045))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any difference? barely.

The compiler should optimize it to be approximately the same.

Here, the difference *in debug mode* is two extra instructions and an additional variable on the stack. Will that be noticeable? Only way to know for sure is to run a benchmark with something like [benchmark.net](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet).

As pointed out in the comments, your code in *release mode* is identical.

You can view the difference with ILSpy, or an online equivalent like [sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQaAEAMgPYDGAhhAGpkBOYZARhAKYAqzAzsDgN454C8ABzoA3MsGZ4azMjCIA7CAE88YBcADaAXTwB9MJIC2HPAF48C5gHcdeHngAMUPOheoXAZhcAWFwFYXADYXAHYXAA4XAE48AF8Abhxk7EE8ZE90nzwAYUUOIhYAdTpJAnVmAAoASn5BPlS0wXEaNWNTCwN2pOw6prwAMyIZMhIACzxKlrbmIzUFGZNaxv6G/v7kdAA6TejKw1nqnvX4vtPelfTM5Gy8hQLi0uZyq1Qas7X1oZHxyemDubqfQAjjLE6fE4CTY7dB7AFHM5pOJnZHYVFAA==)

```
// Methods
    .method public hidebysig 
        instance void ConsoleWriteLine () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2094
        // Code size 39 (0x27)
        .maxstack 2
        .locals init (
            [0] int32[] items,
            [1] int32[],
            [2] int32,
            [3] int32 item
        )

        IL_0000: nop
        IL_0001: ldarg.0
        IL_0002: ldfld int32[] LocalVariableTest::_items
        IL_0007: stloc.0
        IL_0008: nop
        IL_0009: ldloc.0
        IL_000a: stloc.1
        IL_000b: ldc.i4.0
        IL_000c: stloc.2
        // sequence point: hidden
        IL_000d: br.s IL_0020
        // loop start (head: IL_0020)
            IL_000f: ldloc.1
            IL_0010: ldloc.2
            IL_0011: ldelem.i4
            IL_0012: stloc.3
            IL_0013: nop
            IL_0014: ldloc.3
            IL_0015: call void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
            IL_001a: nop
            IL_001b: nop
            // sequence point: hidden
            IL_001c: ldloc.2
            IL_001d: ldc.i4.1
            IL_001e: add
            IL_001f: stloc.2

            IL_0020: ldloc.2
            IL_0021: ldloc.1
            IL_0022: ldlen
            IL_0023: conv.i4
            IL_0024: blt.s IL_000f
        // end loop

        IL_0026: ret
    } // end of method LocalVariableTest::ConsoleWriteLine

    .method public hidebysig 
        instance void ConsoleWriteLine2 () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x20c8
        // Code size 37 (0x25)
        .maxstack 2
        .locals init (
            [0] int32[],
            [1] int32,
            [2] int32 item
        )

        IL_0000: nop
        IL_0001: nop
        IL_0002: ldarg.0
        IL_0003: ldfld int32[] LocalVariableTest::_items
        IL_0008: stloc.0
        IL_0009: ldc.i4.0
        IL_000a: stloc.1
        // sequence point: hidden
        IL_000b: br.s IL_001e
        // loop start (head: IL_001e)
            IL_000d: ldloc.0
            IL_000e: ldloc.1
            IL_000f: ldelem.i4
            IL_0010: stloc.2
            IL_0011: nop
            IL_0012: ldloc.2
            IL_0013: call void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
            IL_0018: nop
            IL_0019: nop
            // sequence point: hidden
            IL_001a: ldloc.1
            IL_001b: ldc.i4.1
            IL_001c: add
            IL_001d: stloc.1

            IL_001e: ldloc.1
            IL_001f: ldloc.0
            IL_0020: ldlen
            IL_0021: conv.i4
            IL_0022: blt.s IL_000d
        // end loop

        IL_0024: ret
    } // end of method LocalVariableTest::ConsoleWriteLine2
```

Comment: In Release mode, sharplab will even show the exact same produced code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I seem to have found the question I want to ask,  the link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229585/in-c-does-copying-a-member-variable-to-a-local-stack-variable-improve-performa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229585/in-c-does-copying-a-member-variable-to-a-local-stack-variable-improve-performa). I searched the question on the search engine before, but I don't seem to know how to describe my idea